# SwiftUI display refresh progresses during batch files uploading

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

Context (macOS app):
The user can select a bunch of images, and after that, I start the uploading of a minimum of 5 files at a time, in parallel. The issue is that I want to display the progress for each image, that I receive from the server. I use `@State` indicator for that array to observe the changes.
Progress status can be: pending, in progress (%), and done.
I need to display the % for each image.

The issue:
The progress is updating very frequently and I need to reflect those changes in the ScrollView.
The layout of the images is displayed as a grid view (square display), but this causes 3 issues:

1. `var body: some View { ... }` is called about 2 - 3 times per second
2. The scroll view is stucked during all those refreshes
3. So many views refresh also causes the memory to spike up to 1gb
   After the uploading is done, the memory is going back to a normal level (50 - 70mb)

I even tried to update the view with a Timer, reflect the changes only once per second but this didn't help a lot.

To improve the rending I included `.id()` for each grid view and for the scroll view, and I could see small improvements over the resources usage, but it's not feeling good enough for a user.

My question is simple, what are the best practices using SwiftUI (1.0) - we need to support macOS 10.15 as well, not just macOS 11 - to achieve this kind of UX, where you can see the progress of the uploading files but you still can scroll to see the pending files or the files that are already uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little hard to really dig into since you didn't provide any code, but here are a few things to think about:

1. Calling `var body: some View { ... } about 2 - 3 times per second` should not on its own be a bottleneck.  I have SwiftUI code that runs at 60 refreshes per second without a hiccup.  However, it *is* an indicator that something inside that `body` call is expensive.  (Impossible to tell without code)
2. Make use of `Equatable` where you can -- **especially for expensive views**.  This will ensure that an expensive view isn't re-rendered when it doesn't need to be.  If you have just a part of a view that is expensive, it would be worth refactoring it out into its own view to become `Equatable`.  More reading on this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-conform-to-the-equatable-protocol
3. Your data model could be refactored to be an `ObservableObject` or `StateObject` with a `Publisher` where you could use Combine to do some clever things to slow down the updates.  First thing that comes to mind is using `throttle` to make sure that your published updates are only being fed back into your views at X interval.  More reading: https://rhonabwy.com/2019/12/15/combine-throttle-and-debounce/
4. Make sure that your uploading work is getting done on a background thread and that your UI updates are coming in on the main thread.  Depending on how you're doing your uploads, Combine might again help you here by letting you call back to the main thread serially when updates come in (possible without Combine, too, but Combine makes things pretty easy).  More reading: http://trycombine.com/posts/subscribe-on-receive-on/
5. Open Instruments and see what's creating all of the memory usage you're seeing.  This should give you a hint to where allocations are happening and where to optimize.

Lastly, SwiftUI `List` performance on Catalina is questionable at best.  It's better on Big Sur.  In SwiftUI 2.0, you could rely more on things like `LazyVStack` but that's not a solution for targeting Catalina.  If you got truly desperate, you could drop back down to AppKit and make your list there, wrapping it in `NSViewRepresentable`

Comment: I used the `Equatable` protocol for some views and it helped a little bit, but digging with Instruments I found that the issue with memory was caused by the `SDWebImageSwiftUI` that is using too much memory and not deallocating it properly. Also, it helped me your answer to clarify some other questions I had. 1) Good to know that SwiftUI handles those kinds of behaviors properly. 2) This helped me to do some optimizations 3) Good to know the right way of doing this 4) I use SotoS3 SDK for uploading and yeah this was already done properly. 5) This helped me to dig in more details

Comment: Regarding SDWebImageSwiftUI I just found this: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI/issues/122

Comment: Great. Glad it pointed you in the right direction